# VB6 - what different of .row and .rows in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, vb6

`If LooseFlexGrid.Row = LooseFlexGrid.Rows - 1 Then`

....

end if

wat is different of .row & .rows ??

Comment: What is the exact problem you're trying to solve? And are you talking about VB 6, or VB.NET (you've tagged your question with both)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `LooseFlexGrid.Row` you can get the selected row's index, and `LooseFlexGrid.Rows` returns the total amount of Rows in your LooseFlexGrid. More info of those can be found at: [Visual Basic: MSFlexGrid/MSHFlexGrid Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa228849%28v=VS.60%29.aspx)

So basically what your code tries to do is to check if the selected row is the last row in `LooseFlexGrid` (because indexing starts from zero, the last row is at index `LooseFlexGrid.Rows - 1`)